# read line from file and save them in a comma separated string to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, cat

I want to read lines from a text file and save them in a variable.

```
  cat ${1} | while read name; do

  namelist=${name_list},${name}

  done
```

the file looks like this:

```
David

Kevin

Steve
etc.
```

and i want to get this output instead

David, Kevin, Steve etc.

and save it to the variable ${name_list}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
name_list=""
for name in `cat file.txt`
   do VAR="$name_list,$i"
done
```

**EDIT**: this script leaves a "," at the beginning of name_list. There are a number of ways to fix this. For example, in bash this should work:

```
name_list=""
for name in `cat file.txt`; do
   if [[ -z $name_list ]]; then
      name_list="$i"
   else
      name_list="$name_list,$i"
   fi  
done
```

**RE-EDIT**: so, thanks to the legitimate complaints of Fredrik:

```
name_list=""
while read name
do 
  if [[ -z $name_list ]]; then
      name_list="$name"
   else
      name_list="$name_list,$name"
   fi
done < file.txt
```

Comment: don't use `cat` for this, especially not in backticks! Proper solution is to use a `while read...; do ...; done < file.txt` construct

Comment: First of all you are using an external program (cat) for something bash is perfectly capable of handling by itself. Secondly, here, the backticks are outright dangerous, unless you know the result of the backticks is going to be less than or equal to how long a command line your shell can accept. Thirdly, you are wasting a process.

Comment: Looks better, if you fix the quotes as well I'd even upvote :-) It will fail if input names contains spaces...

Comment: It works for me even if names contain spaces :P could you fix it for me so I see what you mean?

Comment: If it works for you then you cannot have used the code you have posted :-) You read into a variable called `name` but in the code you are using `i`. The solution I was aiming for is to use `read -r` to prevent bash from splitting on ws and read one complete line at a time.

Comment: lol sorry about that! About `read` splitting name into fields, though, if you meant to say that only the first field is assigned to name that's not true.

Comment: thx for that. the soloution from blue works like a charm for me :)

Answer (score 3):

### The command:

```
$ tr -s '\n ' ',' < sourcefile.txt             # Replace newlines and spaces with [,]
```

This will likely return a `,` as the last character (and potentially the first).
To shave of the comma(s) and return a  satisfying result:

```
$ name_list=$(tr -s '\n ' ',' < sourcefile.txt)      # store the previous result
$ name_list=${tmp%,}                                 # shave off the last comma
$ name_list=${tmp#,}                                 # shave off any first comma
```

---

#### EDIT

This solution runs 44% faster and yields consistent and valid results across all Unix platforms.

```
# This solution
python -mtimeit -s 'import subprocess' "subprocess.call('tmp=$(tr -s "\n " "," < input.txt);echo ${tmp%,} >/dev/null',shell = True)"
100 loops, best of 3: 3.71 msec per loop

# Highest voted:
python -mtimeit -s 'import subprocess' "subprocess.call('column input.txt | sed "s/\t/,/g" >/dev/null',shell = True)"
100 loops, best of 3: 6.69 msec per loop
```

Comment: You can also use something like `printf '%s' "$(<file)" | tr -s '\n ' ','` so the comma will not appear at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Using `column`, and `sed`:

```
namelist=$(column input | sed 's/\t/,/g')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
variable=`perl -lne 'next if(/^\s*$/);if($a){$a.=",$_"}else{$a=$_};END{print $a}' your_file`
```